# Option menu in for loop in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create option menus in a loop, and the number of option menus is dependent on a variable. So I'm trying to use exec in my code.

I used the following to pass the value of 'i' to connect to which variable is changing the value.

But once I call the trace, the option I select in the Option menu, does not get updated in the Option menu box. If I do not call the trace funtion, it is getting updated in the display.

trackProcessMenu is the callback function.

Please let me know, where I am making the mistake.

Adding my code:

```
for i in range(0,numOfLibFiles):
            exec('self.processOptionMenuVar_%d = StringVar()'%i)
            process_menu = ("ff","ss","tt","fff","sss","ttt")
            exec('self.processOptionMenu_%d = OptionMenu(self, self.processOptionMenuVar_%d, *process_menu )'%(i,i))
            exec('self.processOptionMenu_%d.config(indicatoron=0,compound=RIGHT,image= self.downArrowImage, anchor = CENTER , direction = RIGHT)'%i)
            exec('self.processOptionMenuVar_%d.set("--")'%i)
            exec('self.processOptionMenu_%d.grid(row = i, column =1, sticky = N ,padx=30, pady =7 )'%i)

def trackProcessMenu(self,*args):    
    i = args[0]
    exec('process = self.processOptionMenuVar_%d.get()'%i)
```

Comment: Why not using your variables directly (that's what variables are for) instead of creating a string, then exec it?

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Because, this is inside a for loop. I do not know how many instances I require. So I am using exec to create a new name each time for each instance.

Comment: You probably do not need to explicitly name each instance created: placing them in a container (a list maybe?) to keep a reference to them is generally the correct approach.

Comment: How can I use them in a trace function if I add them to a list/dictionary?

Comment: If you want help, post an mvce as suggested earlier.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, I have editted the question and added my code. Please let me know your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `exec` this way. A good rule of thumb is that you should never use `exec` until you can answer the question "why should I never use `exec`?" :-) `exec` has it's uses, but this isn't one of them.

Instead of trying to automagically generate variable names, keep your widgets in a list or dictionary.

For example:

```
option_vars = []
option_menus = []

for i in range(0,numOfLibFiles):
    process_menu = ("ff","ss","tt","fff","sss","ttt")
    var = StringVar()
    om = OptionMenu(self, var, *process_menu)
    om.config(indicatoron=0,compound=RIGHT,image= self.downArrowImage, anchor = CENTER , direction = RIGHT)
    var.set("--")
    om.grid(row = i, column =1, sticky = N ,padx=30, pady =7)

    option_vars.append(var)
    option_menus.append(om)
```

With the above, you can now reference the variables and menus with a simple index:

```
print("option 1 value is:", option_vars[1].get())
```